# WebStorm's main window is vertically unmovable

Tags: awesome-wm, webstorm

When I boot up WebStorm, the main editor window is only draggable and resizable in the horizontal direction. It also is locked to the very top of the screen, obscuring Awesome's system bar.

It is also not affected by any tiling layout, always maintaining its existing position and size, and not affecting the placement of other windows.

Another thing I noticed is this icon next to the window title, only present on the WebStorm windows:

[image: arrow-ish icon]

It looks like a two-sided vertical arrow or something like that.

How can I freely move and resize the window?

Comment: can you check if the problem is specific to certain project? Try deleting `~/.WebStorm<version>` folder to start without projects, then create a new project from Welcome screen - is the main frame still locked to the top?

Comment: @lena It still happens with a clean config and new project.

Comment: what is your screen resolution?

Comment: @lena 2560x1080

Comment: do you use WebStorm in windowed or full screen mode?

Comment: @lena Windowed. In fact, I'm using the default settings.

Comment: @iena Please see the edit, I noticed an icon on the system bar

Comment: no ideas so far.. I'd suggest creating a bug in youtrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) so that we can investigate it further